# Home wifi/broadband unable to load certain sites

Tags: wireless-networking, broadband

The wifi/broadband in my house is failing to load certain sites (nothing dodgy, mainstream ones like bbc.co.uk, skysports.co.uk, so it can't be my ISP attempting some weird blocking). These are inaccessible across multiple devices (iPhone, iPad, Android phone, Windows7 desktop) so it's definitely not a device issue.

Error messages across all browsers/devices are general timeout ones. It appeared to be only .co.uk sites but I am able to connect to others like theregister.co.uk so it's not all of them. When I switch off wifi on my phone and try access sites over mobile data connection it loads them fine, so I know the sites aren't down.

I've rebooted router and also tried changing DNS to both GoogleDNS and OpenDNS without joy.

Any ideas? Anything else I could try? Am I missing something glaringly obvious?

Comment: how old are you? Maybe your parents have a parental control service running :)

Comment: Ha! Good thinking outside the box but no, it's my own broadband, no filters cuz I'm a big boy.

Comment: I have the same problem with different sites. In my case it is due to a routing problems with my ISP making me unable to reach the sites in one data center.  Sadly that includes steadily more CDNs (content delivery networks), effectively blocking youtube, google and 112brabant

Comment: Bummer! I was a bit worried about trying alternative DNS providers cuz of CDNs but broadband use is mostly light browsing so not really an issue. I assume then it's a case of change ISP? (No matter what it shouldn't be stopping me from accessing popular/legit news sites!)

Comment: I would suggest doing a `traceroute` to determine if this is a routing problem with your home network, ISP, or the site in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to have to access xkcd.org instead of xkcd.com for a while with my D-Link Router. The first thing I did was reboot it; it would load once and that's it. I then looked on their website and found a firmware update. I backed up my Router settings and installed the firmware, and it seemed to have worked! So maybe give that a try, and make sure when you try it, you are connecting via ethernet, not wireless.

Finally, have you tried doing a `PING` or `TRACERT` to those sites, and making sure you get replies back? To use these, open the Command Prompt on your Windows 7 system (**Start**, type `cmd` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>), then type `PING bbc.co.uk` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. You should get replies back, along with an IP address. If not, try `TRACERT bbc.co.uk` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. These should be the next troubleshooting methods to try

Comment: I dunno if I'll be able to update my firmware as the router is one we got from ISP, think they're normally locked down, but I'll have a look. I have some powerline adapters so am now connecting my desktop over that instead of wireless, same issue.
Pinging site times out.
Traceroute hops to 8 different places then from 9th onwards times out.#

Comment: When I was forced to use my ex-ISP's router-modem, we could call them to update the firmware manually. Just another option to try. As well, in my country, the ISP provided equipment is to be replaced at no cost if there's no physical damage; maybe ask for a new one

Comment: Looks like the firmware is up-to-date (router is a few years old so probably discontinued).
Thanks for the recommendations. I'll accept as answer because there were some good troubleshooting steps that should always be tried, but it looks like I'll have to go through the pain of ISP customer support :(

Comment: Good luck to you!

Comment: I have come across something very similar to this once before. It's rather strange but the person I was speaking to was unable to browse certain sites and the reason was because his IP address was being spoofed to a German one. May be worth checking your external IP (Whatismyip.com will show you the country).

This is pretty damn unlikely to be your issue but worth a try I guess!

Comment: Also - may be worth checking MTU size in the router, this can prevent you accessing HTTPS sites if it is set too high/low

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an MTU problem. Do you use ADSL/PPPoE? PPPoE limits your MTU to 1492 rather than the common 1500.

You may see if your router supports MSS clamping.

Answer (score 0):

Yes i agreed its all about the MTU size and MSS Clamping.
I was unable to open certain websites on my iPad like i do on my desktop PC, then i changed my ppoe Mtu size from 1492 to 1500, and also enabled MSS Clamping. 
Boommm, everything works flawlessly.